# Открытие текстового файла в новой вкладке в новом TextBox на C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно реализовать текстовый редактор с вкладками. Ну типа чтобы можно было работать с несколькими файлами (один файл открыт в одной вкладке, другой - в другой) как, например, в AkelPad. Написал довольно корявый (и, как оказалось, не рабочий) код. Дело в том, что TextBox в новой вкладке не получает текст из открытого файла, т.е. он остается пустым. Может подскажите, кто знает в чем дело, что тут можно сделать? Пожалуйста ;)

И еще одно! Если не трудно, как растянуть сгенерированное текстовое поле на весь экран программным методом? Ну чтобы свойство Dock было Fill?))
Спасибо.

### Вот мой код:

```
private void открытьВНовойВкладкеToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Выбор файла (для новой вкладки):
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (openFileDialog1.FileName == null) return; // Ничего не делаем, если файл не выбран
// Читаем...
try
 {
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
   {
    TabPage p = new TabPage(openFileDialog1.FileName); // Присваиваем названию новой вкладки название открытого файла
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(p);
    p.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
    TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
    textbox.Location = new Point(100, 100); // Местоположение нового TextBox
    textbox.Visible = true; // Видимость
    textbox.Multiline = true; // Многострочность
    textbox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd(); // Текст нового TextBox присваивает текст открытого файла
    sr.Close(); // Всем спасибо, все свободны
   }
 }
 catch (Exception Unknow_error) // Если ошибка (неизвестная)
  {
   MessageBox.Show(Unknow_error.Message, "Неизвестная ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK); // Показываем сообщение
  }
}
```

Comment: не забывайте в метках указывать какую именно технологию работы с окнами вы используете, WinForms или WPF. Они сильно отличаются.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Почему `textbox` остается пустым?

> p.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
>   TextBox textbox = new TextBox();

Тут все просто, вы во вкладку кладете один `textbox`, а после этого создаете другой и настраиваете уже его, и текст кладете в него же. Исправить просто:

```
...
TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
p.Controls.Add(textbox);  
...
```

2. Свойство `Dock` вы можете настроить как и любое другое, просто присвоив ему нужное значение `textbox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ! Все работает. Но мне хотелось бы еще уточнить как я могу получить доступ к textbox который находится в активной вкладке? Вот, например, так я получаю доступ к активной вкладке 'tabControl1.SelectedTab', а как мне так до textbox добраться чтобы сохранять/печатать/очищать текст именно с textbox на активной вкладке?

Comment: @StepanKo а это лучше отдельным вопросом. В двух словах не получится, есть варианты.